# In VBA I'm trying to subtract 2 cells, then comparing them, then adding the initial value to the left of cell in which formula is used

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function SubNSum(a As Double, c As Double, rng As Range) As Double
Dim x As Double
Dim y As Double
Dim z As Double
'Dim b As Double
'b = 0
'q-d>=o and <=f2
    For Each Cell In rng
        'x = a - c
        x = Cell.Value - a
        If ((x > 0) Or (x = 0)) Then
            If ((x < c) Or (x = c)) Then
                'b = b + 1
                y = Cell.Row
                z = Cell.Column
                Cells(y, z - 1).Value = Cells(y, z - 1).Value + x
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
    'SubNSum = b
End Function
```

Comment: What's your question, or the error?

Comment: This will not worked as  UDF called from the worksheet.  If it is not called from the worksheet but other vba code then make it a sub.

Comment: its not adding anything to left cell

Comment: infact its giving #value| error

Comment: didnt get you scott craner

Comment: A function called from the worksheet cannot change the value of any other cell than the one in which the formula is placed.

Comment: No, I need a function

Comment: Not possible as a UDF called from the worksheet, except in some edge cases.

Comment: oh, now i get it

Comment: will same thing work if turn this in to sub?

Comment: Yes, because a `Sub` can modify the sheet.

Comment: can I call both ranges here? will it affect that cell then?

Comment: You only need to pass one range; you can refer to the left cell with `Offset`.

Comment: I have used offset with vloockup but how will I use it here

Comment: you cannot call a sub from the worksheet, it will need a trigger.